# How can I store several values in Application storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xamarin.forms

How can I store several values in xamarin forms using Application storage just like the way its done in asp.net.

```
 <add key="IDs" value="1,2,3,4,5,6" />
```

How can I achieve the above in xamarin forms using Application storage?

Comment: What types of values you want to store. like session?

Comment: I want to store my formulae Keys for checking if a measure requires numeric ids

Comment: You can use enums for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can choose:

**1.   List**

```
List<int> IDs2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6  };

 foreach (int id in IDs2) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("id = " + id);
 }
```

**2.   Array**

```
 int[] IDs = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
 // get the value by index of array.e.g.(IDs[1])
 for (int i=0;i<IDs.Length;i++) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("id = " + IDs[i]);
   }
```

**3.   ArrayList**

```
 ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
 for (int i=0;i<=6;i++) {
     arrayList.Add(i);
 }

 for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
  {
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("id = " + arrayList.Get(i));
  }
```

**4.   emum**

```
enum IDs
    {  //  init value
        Value1 = 1,
        Value2 = 2,
        Value3 = 3,
        Value4 = 4,
        Value5 = 5,
        Value6 = 6
    }
```

And use like this:

```
 int value1 = (int)IDs.Value1;
```

**Note：the difference**

They are different object types. They have different capabilities and store their data in different ways. You may as well ask what is the difference between a decimal and a DateTime.

`An Array` (System.Array) is fixed in size once it is allocated. You can't add items to it or remove items from it. Also, all the elements must be the same type. As a result, it is type safe, and is also the most efficient of the three, both in terms of memory and performance. Also, System.Array supports multiple dimensions (i.e. it has a Rank property) while List and ArrayList do not (although you can create a List of Lists or an ArrayList of ArrayLists, if you want to).

`An ArrayList` is a flexible array which contains a list of objects. You can add and remove items from it and it automatically deals with allocating space. If you store value types in it, they are boxed and unboxed, which can be a bit inefficient. Also, it is not type-safe.

`A List<>` leverages generics; it is essentially a type-safe version of ArrayList. This means there is no boxing or unboxing (which improves performance) and if you attempt to add an item of the wrong type it'll generate a compile-time error.

`enum` types are typically used to list unique elements, such as days of the week and country/territory names